# Do a simple seach regardless of upper an lower case

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain to me, how I can do in javascript this simple code, without taking care of upper and lower case?

```
if(res.search('em')!=-1){  unit='em'; res.replace(unit,'');}
if(res.search('vh')!=-1){  unit='vh'; res.replace(unit,'');}
if(res.search('px')!=-1){  unit='px'; res.replace(unit,'');}
```

Without any idea, that is what I have coded. It's a lot of code

```
if(res.search('Em')!=-1){  unit='Em'; res.replace(unit,'');}
if(res.search('eM')!=-1){  unit='eM'; res.replace(unit,'');}
if(res.search('EM')!=-1){  unit='EM'; res.replace(unit,'');}
...
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do that!?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well add some examples how `res` looks like. that will help you to get much better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part you can use `toLowerCase()`

`if(res.toLowerCase().search('em') != -1)`

You can use alternation in regex alongside case insensitive flag.

`/(em|vh|px)/i` Mathces `em` or `vh` or `px`.

```js
function replaceUnit(input){
  return input.replace(/(em|px|vh)/i ,'replaced')
}

console.log(replaceUnit('height: 20em'))
console.log(replaceUnit('width:=20Em'))
console.log(replaceUnit('border-radius: 2Px'))
console.log(replaceUnit('unit=pX'))
console.log(replaceUnit('max-height=20Vh'))
```

Comment: thats looks great, but i need to know the value of unit from the search. I need this later in the code

Comment: @RainerS yeah for the you can use `toLowerCase()`. anyway you need not to check explicitly here it will replace only if it finds em, px or vh. otherwise it will return the original string back.

Comment: ok, i see but i need the value of unit, the match of the search, i need this for later in the code

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with `replace` and save the found unit as a side effect of the replacer function. This would allow you to replace the unit without searching the string twice:

```js
let res = "Value of 200Em etc."
let unit
let newRes = res.replace(/(em|vh|px)/i, (found) => {unit = found.toLowerCase(); return ''})

console.log("replaced:", newRes, "Found Unit:", unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), transform all the string to lower case and compare,

```
var tobereplaced = 'em';

if(res.search.toLowerCase(tobereplaced)> -1){   res.replace(tobereplaced,'');}
```

Comment: thats easy, only a question whats the fastes way!?

Comment: @RainerS this is probably the fastest way.

Comment: for the search it matched, but the replace wont work in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to to is force your string to lowercase (or uppercase) before testing its contents:

```
if( res.toLowerCase().search('em') !== -1){ do(stuff); }
```

To handle replacing the actual substring value in res, something like this should work:

```
let caseInsensitiveUnit = "em";
let unitLength;
let actualUnit;
let position = res.toLowerCase().search(caseInsensitiveUnit);
if(position > -1){ 
    unitLength = caseInsensitiveUnit.length; 
    actualUnit = res.substring(postion, position + unitLength);
    res.replace(actualUnit, "");
}
```

Comment: for the search it will be the easiest way, but for the replace i think its not a way?

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify how replacing could work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make these three assumptions:

1. The string always starts with a number
2. The string always ends with a unit
3. The unit is always two characters

Then it could be as simple as:

```
const str = '11.5px';
const unit = str.substr(-2); //=> 'px'
const value = parseFloat(str, 10); //=> 11.5
```

Or with a function:

```
const parse = str => ({unit: str.substr(-2), value: parseFloat(str, 10)});
const {unit, value} = parse('11.5px');
// unit='px', value=11.5
```