# How to change this code for working with a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54259074/519413) I tried, but failed, to change the code in a way to use it for a single element.

I want to recieve the CSS part of, for example, `border-radius` for a `div` element I have clicked on. What do I have to change in the function `getCssByRule()` so that it works?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e) {
  var css_now = getCssByRule('border-radius', this);
}

function getCssByRule(rule, element) {
  const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
    .filter(e => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule)) !== 0)
    .map(e => window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule));

  return values;
}

console.log('getCssByRule' + getCssByRule('margin-left', element));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the syntax errors then your code works. To do that, add the missing `)` in the `on()` block, and remove the `console.log()` as it was referencing `element` when it was out of scope. If you want to see the value of the CSS property, put a `console.log()` inside the click event handler.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e) {
  var radius = getCssByRule('border-radius', this);
  console.log(radius);
});

function getCssByRule(rule, element) {
  const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
    .filter(e => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule)) !== 0)
    .map(e => window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue(rule));

  return values;
}
```

```css
.myclass {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Foo</div>
```

That being said, you're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. You're already including jQuery to attach the `click` event handler so why not use it to get the CSS setting of the `border-radius`? It's a one-liner:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(e) {
  var css_now = $(this).css('border-radius');
  console.log(css_now);
});
```

```css
.myclass {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Foo</div>
```

Comment: in your both snippets, are inside the console no result for the border radius !? may me function work not correct?

Comment: if i understand my code correctly, the given element wont not touch/use?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying, but I gather this is not working for you. As you can see in the snippet, it works fine. If you have issues, please edit your question to include your current logic which you have the issues with